# Type name 'serializeObject' does not exist in the type 'JsonConvert'

Tags: asp.net-core, cloudflare

I am trying to convert some data to Json to send to the CloudFlare API. I am attempting to use Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SeriablizeObject() to accomplish this but I am getting the Intellisense error that the type name 'serializeObject' does not exist in the type 'JsonConvert'. I have the NuGet package Newtonsoft.Json installed but it does not recognize the SerializeObject() method. I am not sure what I am missing.

[image]

Comment: clean, remove bin and obj folder, rebuild before trying anything btw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because you're calling the method wrong, remove the new operator from the line

```
var json = new JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updateDnsRecord);
```

to

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updateDnsRecord);
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. I both love and hate when it is easy. I feel like an idiot but it doesn't take long

Comment: I get what you're saying, and it wont get better with experience its something that sticks though your whole career i feel like. But thats the bane and beaty of SE. Go ahead and mark this answer with completion if you could.

Comment: I will. It is telling me I have to wait 6 minutes

Comment: @reusablePants ah okay. Yeah there seems to be some wait time nowadays - i dont remember that being there anymore. Still feel like there are so many open questions on SO that could've been closed so im trying to do my part.